# In my Python Discord Bot, the @client.command (or commonly used is @bot.command) does not work

Tags: python, discord, atom-editor

I'm quite new to Python and the Discord API in general. I use Atom for my script editor and it even registers that the "@client" part of @client.command. It used to turn blue but now only the .command part turns blue. I may be mistaken, but this is my problem.

My code:

```
@client.command(aliases = ["8ball"])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ["It is certain.",
                "It is decidedly so.",
                "Without a doubt.",
                "Yes - definitely.",
                "You may rely on it.",
                "As I see it, yes.",
                "Most likely.",
                "Outlook good.",
                "Yes.",
                "Signs point to yes.",
                "Reply hazy, try again.",
                "Ask again later.",
                "Better not tell you now.",
                "Cannot predict now.",
                "Concentrate and ask again.",
                "Don't count on it.",
                "My reply is no.",
                "My sources say no.",
                "Outlook not so good.",
                "Very doubtful."]
    await ctx.send(f"Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}")
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What's the error stack trace you are getting after running your code? You should edit your question with those details.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean